# CSS grid and flex box alignment issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

so I was making this layout and i can't get the header to be aligned properly
I want to move the button and heading to the red boxes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvjMq.png)

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="notes__title">Notes</h1>
    <button class="notes__create">Create</button>
  </div>
  <div class="notes">
    <div class="note">
      <h3 class="note__title">Note Title</h3>
      <div class="note__body">Text....</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the CSS

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.notes__title {
    color: #fff;
}
.notes {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
```

please help

Comment: Please show all your code for help over code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using space-around which is what causes the effect you are seeing.

Try:

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: nope, unfortunately does not work.

Comment: it goes to the edges of the screen instead of being aligned

Comment: Make your header and notes the same width.

Comment: @SalehMubashar set max-width of header to "1200px" too. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: nope, this just causes the items to stick together, ie. worse off than before

Answer (score 0):

ok so i did this and it worked
although I am not happy with the solution, i wanted to achieve it with flex box only#

```
.main {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Weird  that the previous solution didn't work. Can you also swap the values of width and max-width and see if that works? Like this (width: 1200px, max-width: 100%);

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution I can think of is using bootstrap cols and use the space-between for Notes and Button to got to the right place

Comment: To broad as an answer. You should provide a specific solution and not just a hint in certain direction.